# Verify case-sensitive Password in asp.net using sql server during login

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, c#-4.0

**Return Successful**

```
Dim user = "ravi"
        Dim pass = "admin"
        objcmd.CommandText = "Select * from ADMIN_INFO where ADMIN_ID='" & user & "' and ADMIN_PASS='" & pass & "'"
```

**Return Successful**

```
Dim user = "ravi"
        Dim pass = "ADMIN"
        objcmd.CommandText = "Select * from ADMIN_INFO where ADMIN_ID='" & user & "' and ADMIN_PASS='" & pass & "'"
```

After execution of query, both return successful, where as in table only `ravi` and `admin` is available. So, how can i check for case-sensitivity. Need help !!

Comment: Change the table column's COLLATION property, no?

Comment: is there any solution, that i can do in my asp.net coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
(
    Password Varchar(2)
)
insert into #temp values('a')
```

### First Approach

```
select Password  from #temp Where Password COLLATE Latin1_general_CS_AS  = 'A' 
select Password  from #temp Where Password COLLATE Latin1_general_CS_AS  = 'a'
```

### Second Approach

```
select Password  from #temp Where cast(Password as varbinary(2))  = cast('A' as varbinary(15)) 
select Password  from #temp Where cast(Password as varbinary(2))  = cast('a' as varbinary(15))
```

---

```
drop table #temp
```

Comment: `@ password COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1` doesn't require single cots or double cots ..??

Comment: i searched every where i got the same solution, but the problem is, i'm getting error says `@pass` is not declare.

Answer (score 2):

This article may help you: [Case sensitive search in SQL Server queries](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/case_sensitive_search_in_sql_server.htm). However, it isn't usually good practice to save your passwords in plain text to begin with.

Also, you could just select the admin row from your database, and then do the password comparison on the .Net side where the comparison is case-sensitive by default.

```
bool result = string1.Equals(string2); //this is case sensitive unless you specify otherwise
```